# How to Calculate a 2D Empirical CDF via histogram2d

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability, sample

I am trying to obtain a matrix representation of an empirical 2 dimensional CDF given two data samples of the same size.

I have two sorted data samples of the same size: `sorted_sample1` and `sorted_sample2` . I want a matrix which represents their 2 dimensional empirical cdf. Currently I have

```
hist_values, x_edges, y_edges = np.histogram2d(sorted_sample1, sorted_sample2,density = True, bins=[num_bins_x, num_bins_y], range=bin_range)
```

This gives me a 2 dimensional empirical PDF. If this were 1D then I would apply `np.sumsum` to my empirical pdf and then normalise in order to get the CDF. However, I'm not sure what to do for the 2D case. The two options I've come up with are:

1. `np.cumsum` along one axis and then along the other. But this feels wrong and I'm wondering whether the order of axis matters: `cumsum_x = np.cumsum(hist_values1, axis=0)` followed by  `cumsum1_xy = np.cumsum(cumsum1_x, axis=1)` . Then I can normalise
2. unravel my 2D matrix and apply cumsum to that, and then reshape it: `` `cumsum = np.cumsum(hist_values.ravel()).reshape(hist_values1.shape) ``  . Then I can normalise

   Is either of these options correct and if not what is? Thanks

Comment: What do do mean "sorted data samples of the same size"? This is 2D samples, how you could sort them? And have them sorted at the same time? Could you please provide sample of the data1 and data2?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux both sets of samples are measurements of a network. They have the same length.

Comment: But they are 2D points. Suppose I've got points (2,3) and (1,4), so x=[2,1] and y=[3,4], and that would be input for np.histogram2d. How you could sort them? You could make x equal to [1,2], but that completely breaks the distribution to be histrogrammed. Could you edit the question and put out how your data looks like and meaning of "sorted"?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I dont think they are 2D points. One sample is say the degrees of all the nodes and the other is for example a centrality measure of the nodes. I am interested in the distribution of both quantities

Comment: You could think of them anything, for the purpose of the collecting 2D histogram they are 2D points unzipped into X and Y array. But it means that you CANN'T sort them independently, X[i] and Y[i] came from he same event, you cannot unhinge them.

Comment: posted an answer, and you could check how sorting will affect it

Comment: updated for the case of non-uniform grids

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is simple illustration. 2D gaussian with some correlation. Run code twice, one without sort and once with a sort. You could see that sorting destroy your dependency

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mean = [0, 0]
cov = [[1, 1.2], [1.2, 3]]  # diagonal covariance

x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 1000).T

#x = np.sort(x)

plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Anyway, this is what I think you're looking for. You have to integrate
density (PDF) to get CDF as Prob(x≤X,y≤Y).

For histogram representation, it means that CDF is actually defined not in the middle of the bin, but actually in the bin upper right corner, this is where you could pick those X,Y for inequality above.

Code, Python 3.10, Windows 10 x64

```
mean = [0, 0]
cov = [[1, 1.2], [1.2, 3]]  # diagonal covariance

x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 5000).T

# remove outliners

i = np.where(x > -3)
x = x[i]
y = y[i]

i = np.where(x < 3)
x = x[i]
y = y[i]

i = np.where(y > -4)
x = x[i]
y = y[i]

i = np.where(y < 4)
x = x[i]
y = y[i]

# plot scatter plot

plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()

# histogram and plotting

hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(40, 50), range=((-3,3), (-4,4)), density=True)

dx = xedges[1] - xedges[0]
dy = yedges[1] - yedges[0]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
ax1.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, hist.T)

cdf = hist.cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1)*dx*dy

ax2.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, cdf.T)
plt.show()
```

You should have CDF in upper right corner bin to be 1,

```
print(cdf[-1,-1])
```

produced

```
1.000000000004
```

In the case of non-uniform grid, dx and dy should be arrays

```
dx=xedges[1:]-xedges[:-1]
dy=yedges[1:]-yedges[:-1]
```

and should be used to multiply pdf along the proper axes

And pics

[image]

PDF and CDF
[image]